# What does the 'A' stand for in the Material Design color swatch system? (e.g tealA200)

Tags: color, material-design, color-scheme

[image]

Sort of a rudimentary question, so I apologize in advance. Just curious what the `A` mean and maybe more broadly, are there any design implications I should be considering in relation to the meaning. Like, does `A` denote that it is an accent color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### They are used for 'accent' colors.

See [this video, which explains the number system](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJ3ra4v6_VAhVGlVQKHX9IB0IQtwIIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmaterial.io%2Fguidelines%2Fstyle%2Fcolor.html&usg=AFQjCNExmbrIT44Pv38qlPXsaFIRoHmcVA), all the way to the A (accent) colors. It's an approach to build the proper amount of harmony and contrast where needed.

**500 series** colors are considered 'Primary' and scales from there to lighter or darker colors. Used for the dominant theme in your UI.

**700 series** is recommended for elements like status bars.

**300 series** for secondary info elements.

**A series colors** are designed to indicate interaction. They recommend this series for highlighting primary action buttons. They describe them as giving a 'pop' of color.